# find similar items following each other in a python list

Tags: python, list

How can I find similar items following each other in a list. For example:

```
list = ["A","B", "B", "C", "A", "A" ]

#output:

A-1, B-1, B-2, C-1, A-1, A-2
```

Comment: does second a is a-2 or a-1? what is pattern

Comment: yes, first a is a-1, second a is a-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ["A","B", "B", "C", "A", "A" ]
>>> ['{}-{}'.format(x, i) for k, g in groupby(lst) for i, x in enumerate(g, 1)]
['A-1', 'B-1', 'B-2', 'C-1', 'A-1', 'A-2']
```

If you need a string as output then use `str.join`:

```
>>> ", ".join('{}-{}'.format(x, i) for k, g in groupby(lst) for i, x in enumerate(g, 1))
'A-1, B-1, B-2, C-1, A-1, A-2'
```

What `groupby` does is that it groups items by values(Or with a key function if we provide any) and then we are looping over each group using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index as well as item.

Comment: +1 excellent answer! Put some explanation so that OP and other user can learn

Comment: @MitulShah, thanks for that. What about if i want to use strings instead of index, for example; `A-first, A-second`. Is there a better approach instead of splitting each item and replacing `1` with `first` and `2` with `second`

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["A","B", "B", "C", "A", "A" ]
stri=''
counter=1
for i in list:
    if stri!=i:
        stri=i
        counter=1
    else:
        counter+=1
    print stri,'-',counter
```

explanation for code:

1. take a variable `stri` to track the letter and counter to get the count
2. if `stri!=i` assign new stri else increment the counter